# Riak Yokuzuna Schema upload , create index and search query always result in error 60,56,27

Tags: riak, riak-search, yokozuna

```
public class RiakSearch {
public static final String RIAK_SERVER = "10.11.172.17";

private static RiakCluster setUpCluster() throws UnknownHostException {
    // This example will use only one node listening on localhost:10017
    RiakNode node = new RiakNode.Builder()
            .withRemoteAddress("10.11.172.17")
            .withAuth("administrator", "password@123", null).build();

    // This cluster object takes our one node as an argument
    RiakCluster cluster = new RiakCluster.Builder(node).build();

    // The cluster must be started to work, otherwise you will see errors
    cluster.start();

    return cluster;
}

public void uploadSchema() {
    try {
        RiakCluster cluster = setUpCluster();
        RiakClient client = new RiakClient(cluster);
        System.out.println("Client object successfully created");
        File xml = new File("blog_post_schema.xml");
        String xmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(xml);
        YokozunaSchema schema = new YokozunaSchema("blog_post_schema",
                xmlString);
        StoreSchema storeSchemaOp = new StoreSchema.Builder(schema).build();
        client.execute(storeSchemaOp);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RiakSearch obj = new RiakSearch();
    obj.uploadSchema();

}

}
```

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.basho.riak.client.core.netty.RiakResponseException: Unknown message code: 56
>       at com.basho.riak.client.core.FutureOperation.get(FutureOperation.java:260)
>       at com.basho.riak.client.api.commands.CoreFutureAdapter.get(CoreFutureAdapter.java:52)
>       at com.basho.riak.client.api.RiakCommand.execute(RiakCommand.java:89)
>       at com.basho.riak.client.api.RiakClient.execute(RiakClient.java:293)
>       at com.search.RiakSearch.main(RiakSearch.java:64)
>   Caused by: com.basho.riak.client.core.netty.RiakResponseException: Unknown message code: 56
>       at com.basho.riak.client.core.netty.RiakResponseHandler.channelRead(RiakResponseHandler.java:52)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:84)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
>       at io.netty.channel.PausableChannelEventExecutor.invokeChannelRead(PausableChannelEventExecutor.java:86)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:389)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:243)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.channelRead(ByteToMessageCodec.java:103)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:84)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
>       at io.netty.channel.PausableChannelEventExecutor.invokeChannelRead(PausableChannelEventExecutor.java:86)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:389)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:956)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:127)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:514)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:471)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:385)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:351)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
>       at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1412)
>       at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:280)
>       at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:877)
>       at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1706)
>       at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1661)
>       at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:126)

Comment: What do you see in Riak logs (/var/log/riak/)? Especially /var/log/riak/solr.log

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that Solr is actually started. By default, search is disabled in Riak 2.x. In order to enable it, change `search` property in /etc/riak/riak.conf to `on`. Then restart Riak.

Comment: Also, make sure that if you do have search enabled to give it a little time to start.  I tried to connect as soon as the main Riak server started, but then Solr took an extra few seconds to get started.  This was using a localhost single node for development.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue of 
`RiakError: 'Unknown message code: 56'`

I solved it by changing the parameter of search in the 'riak.conf' file
Here is the file location, if you are using mac and installed via brew

`/usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.2.2/libexec/etc/riak.conf`

Here are the lines of code i changed from off to on

```
## To enable Search set this 'on'.
## 
## Default: off
## 
## Acceptable values:
##   - on or off
search = on
```

I found the [documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.2/configuring/search/#search-config-settings) explanation a little bit tricky to follow but more or less it is the reference to solve the issue.